# What is the point/utility of addEvents? When would it be useful?

Tags: extjs

I saw that it adds events to an Observable. However, you would only add it if you would fire it at some point. So, if you add the firing of the event at some line in your code, it was useless to put it into addEvents in the first place and when you don't place the fireEvent in your code then it was pointless to include it in addEvents. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding custom events with your component then you must add the events with addEvent before you can fire the events with fireEvent. Adding and firing events is useful in binding custom components together without explicitly referencing them.